# Reading geo-tiff file using raster() ggplot fails with no error message. What causes this error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geo, r-raster

I'm attempting to learn how to import, display, and generally handle geo-tiff files in R-Studio and notebook. When I run the code I get no errors. The plot is not displayed but entering the plot name in the console gives an error. It's as if an error is detected, the plot is still created, but no error is reported either by running the chunks or by running 'knit'.

> `fimage_plot    Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

My code chunk:

```
rlist <- list.files(tiffTestFldrOrig, pattern="tif$",
                full.names=TRUE)
for(tiff_path_nane in rlist) {
  fimage <- raster(tiff_path_nane)
  fill_col_name = names(fimage)
  fimage_df <- as.data.frame(fimage, xy = TRUE)

  fimage_plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data = fimage_df, aes(x=x, y=y, 
              fill = fill_col_name)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(type = "gradient") +
    coord_quickmap()

  fimage_plot # no plot displayed, no error
  break() # until error corrected
}
```

I've tried google, searching on various `scale_fill_discete`, `scale_fill_continous`, etc. to no avail.

BTW my x & y data are UTM with the third column 16 bit integer values representing temperatures of a wildfire.

Comment: Hi Nate, can you provide a minimal [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: @Majid, I can, but how can I provide the 525 KB GEOTIFF data file?

Comment: You may either `dput()` small portion of your data or make a minimal reproducible example as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658006/how-to-create-10-random-rasters-in-r?answertab=active#tab-top). I don't think that data needs to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because in:

```r
geom_raster(data = fimage_df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = fill_col_name))
```

you are using a character variable to specify fill. `ggplot` does not like that.

You can either avoid changing the names of `fimage` and then use

```r
 geom_raster(data = fimage_df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = layer))
```

as in @Majid reply, or use `aes_string` to associate the character variable to `fill`:

```r
 geom_raster(data = fimage_df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", fill = fill_col_name))
```

(Note however that `aes_string` is soft deprecated: in the future it may stop working and you'll have to use tidy evaluation.)

HTH

Comment: "ggplot doesn't like that" But it won't complain until until  you try to display it.  :-(   I figured it out yesterday and guess I didn't attempt verify that it worked earlier since there were no errors when the code ran.  What replaces the deprecated 'as_data_frame', I don't like to ignore warnings.

Comment: `as_data_frame` is going to be replaced by `as_tibble`, I think.

Comment: AFAIK 'as_tibble' can't handle raster layers, sigh, at least it crashed when I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

OK @Nate I did something roughly by generating example data myself. Hope it works and that is what you wanted:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, 
             xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.3)
fimage <- lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1))))
fimage_plot <- list()

for(i in 1:length(fimage)) {
  fimage_df <- as.data.frame(fimage[[i]], xy = TRUE)

  fimage_plot[[i]] <- ggplot(fimage_df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_raster(aes(fill = layer)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=paste0("Plot ", i))) # if you want to change the legend

  fimage_plot[[i]]  
  # break() # until error corrected
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  See my comment to ibusett. I'm trying to learn R and to import and work with the data in GEOTIFF files.

Comment: Whether or not the data is in geotiff files is not relevant to your question about using ggplot. This is how you set up a question --- without using files.

Comment: One of the frustrating aspects of R is trying to figure out what the error messages mean.  There was no error message emitted in building the plot, just in displaying it.  In hindsight I see that a simple example would have excluded the file type as being relevant.